# Magento2 Custom Email send?

Tags: magento2

I added custom html form in magento2 page. In magento2 default contact form will be there, it will work normally.But my custom email not send. How to send the custom mail with user and admin?

Comment: Please, find the link below and refer accepted answer.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198838/how-to-create-a-custom-form-for-sending-email-with-file-attachment-in-magento-2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

**1. Create new html file**

/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/email/modulename/test.html

```
<div>

Hello, Test email.

</div>
```

**2. Declare your email template, create xml file**

/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/email_templates.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:Magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="modulename_test_template" label="Test email" file="modulename/test.html" type="html" module="VendorName_ModuleName" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

**3. Finally, create a function to send your email.**

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Sendemail extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $_request;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    , \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    , \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    , \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
)
{
    $this->_request = $request;
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('modulename_test_template')
        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
        ->setTemplateVars(
            [
                'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
            ]
        )
        ->setFrom('general')
        // you can config general email address in Store -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses
        ->addTo('customer@email.com', 'Customer Name')
        ->getTransport();
    $transport->sendMessage();
    return $this;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

---

check the flow,you create new contact form,then you can get the form data from HTTPREquestInterface,then reference the above answer for sending email,you can then send the email with custom form

---

```php
public function execute()
{
    $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('modulename_test_template')
        ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store])
        ->setTemplateVars(
            [
                'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(),
            ]
        )
        ->setFrom('general')
        // you can config general email address in Store -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses
        ->addTo('customer@email.com', 'Customer Name')
        ->getTransport();
    $transport->sendMessage();
    return $this;
}

//customer@email.com---can get it from httpRequest
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO if you answer a question please explain your answer. That way the person who asks the question also understands the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following method given here to send custom Emails programmatically in Magento 2.

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        StateInterface $state
    )
    {
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $state;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        // this is an example and you can change template id,fromEmail,toEmail,etc as per your need.
        $templateId = 'my_custom_email_template'; // template id
        $fromEmail = 'owner@domain.com';  // sender Email id
        $fromName = 'Admin';             // sender Name
        $toEmail = 'customer@email.com'; // receiver email id

        try {
            // template variables pass here
            $templateVars = [
                'msg' => 'test',
                'msg1' => 'test1'
            ];

            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

            $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

            $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $templateOptions = [
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $storeId
            ];
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId, $storeScope)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($toEmail)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please First install SMTP marketplace module and set mail after applying code
link :https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).